# Hook useEffect rendering as per array list

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, callback, redux-toolkit

I am working on blog post creation

```
const { isError, message, isSuccess } = useSelector((state) => state.post);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
  if (isError && message) {
    toast.error(message);
  }
  if (isSuccess && message) {
    toast.success(message);
  }
  return () => {
    dispatch(clearPost());
  };
}, [dispatch, isError, isSuccess, message]);
```

`clearPost()` action is for clearing all the loading, error, success states.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAsvV.png)

I know the `useEffect` callback is triggered everytime when the value in dependency array changes. My question is what should I do to the dependency array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by what should you do to the dependency array?

Comment: is something unexpected happening in your code?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?